# Finding a div that is currently in a scroll state during run time. -Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, safari

There is a div somewhere that is causing a scroll issue (only happening on Safari), the scrolling overrides the contents scrolling, causing it to lock the scroll until the scroll bar disappears. This happens when I attempt to `scroll up` at the top of the page.

What I'm looking for is a way to log when `any` div is currently in the `scroll` state, so I can pause the debugger and find its location/whats rendering it and turning off its overflow.

I'm about to cmd+f every div and add a console log for `onScroll` to each one.. but I'd love to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Did you figure out how to debug this for Safari? I'm having the same problem, but just in Safari on iOS. The main element that scrolls is expected, but there is a mystery "undefined" element that is scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
  debugger;
  // add more code if you need, e.target is the actual element scrolling
}, true);
```

Note the "true" as the third parameter, that makes the event listener to capture the event also triggered by the children.